# Printing output from string building function not returning expected result

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm writing a function to output a basic hours & minutes string in 24 hour format from two global int's containing hours and minutes.

I've defined these during initialization:

```
int g_alarmHours = 7;
int g_alarmMinutes = 0;
```

The function to return the string is:

```
char* getAlarmTime() {
  int hours = g_alarmHours;
  int minutes = g_alarmMinutes;
  char t[6];
  t[0] = (hours/10) + '0';
  t[1] = (hours%10) + '0';
  t[2] = ':';
  t[3] = (minutes/10) + '0';
  t[4] = (minutes%10) + '0';
  t[5] = 0;
  return t;
}
```

The global variables are stubs to be replaced when serial comms to another device are added where those values will be retrieved from.

Calling the function generates the following hex values at the character pointer:

```
0x20 0x4b 0x00
```

When I replace the top two lines of the `getAlarmTime()` function with the following

```
int hours = 7;
int minutes = 0;
```

The output is then what I expect, of:

```
07:00\0
```

Why is using those global variables causing the output of `getAlarmTime()` to go so wonky?

Comment: Out of Curiosity What does `t[5] = 0;` mean?

Comment: @Rohit assigning the null character to the last array element

Comment: Isnt `'\0'` the `null` character.

Comment: @Rohit, `'\0' == 0`. I was just being a lazy typist and taking the shortest route to the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to a local variable on the stack. The memory the pointer is pointing at is no longer valid and accessing that memory invokes undefined behavior. The reason why you are seeing such strange behavior is because anything can happen when you invoke undefined behavior.

The solution to your problem would be to code in C++ and use std::string.

```
std::string t;
t.push_back((hours/10) + '0');
...

return t;
```

Comment: I'm doing this on an arduino with 4KB memory and a lot of code being executed including a mini-webserver, I'd prefer to avoid the string library if possible because it has quite a heavy footprint. I understand what you're saying though, I'm assuming the other solution not involving that is to declare the character array outside of the function and pass the pointer in as an argument for it to use as a buffer to write out to.

Comment: @bdx: Are you familiar with the [String class](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringObject?from=Reference.StringClass)?

Comment: I am, but have been warned repeatedly that it has a much larger memory footprint than character arrays when it's included. I'm pushing close to the RAM limits as it is, I'm looking for ways to cut back my memory usage wherever possible.

Comment: @bdx: Then your solution would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a pointer to an array that is local to your function only. Thus when your function exits the array that was created in your function no longer exists and any attempt to access that memory will result in undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is using those global variables causing the output of getAlarmTime() to go so wonky?

You are actually looking at undefined behavior here, because you are returning the address of a local (stack) variable.

The following sequence takes place:

- You call `getAlarmTime`.
- compiler allocates stack space for it's variables (hours, minutes and t).
- Then t is filled
- you return t's address.
- control exits function and the address you returned points to unused stack space.

Subsequent stack data (variables declared afterwards or other function calls) will overwrite this space.

**Solution:** Consider returning a `std::string` instead of a `char*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a Local variable as pointer.

`return t;`

The Ideone compiler returned the following error while compiling:

> prog.cpp: In function ‘char* getAlarmTime()’: prog.cpp:8:8: warning:
>   address of local variable ‘t’ returned [-Wreturn-local-addr]    char
>   t[6];

But i don't understand how it works when you replace the 1st 2 lines with

```
int hours = 7;
int minutes = 0;
```

Use string or pass by deference to solve your issue. Or even a Global variable can solve your issue.

Comment: It appears to be blind luck that it works consistently when I do that.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Didnt it return any Warning (if not Error) when you attempted the return

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a pointer to a local array. It is destroyed before the caller can access it, giving undefined behaviour; in practice it may or may not be overwritten with someone else's data.

The usual solution would be to return a dynamic array (such as `std::string`); but since you say you have extreme memory restrictions that would be a bad idea here.

I would modify the function so that the caller supplies the buffer:

```
void getAlarmTime(char t[6]) {
  int hours = g_alarmHours;
  int minutes = g_alarmMinutes;
  t[0] = (hours/10) + '0';
  t[1] = (hours%10) + '0';
  t[2] = ':';
  t[3] = (minutes/10) + '0';
  t[4] = (minutes%10) + '0';
  t[5] = 0;
}
```

Beware that the caller is now responsible for making sure the buffer is large enough. Even though I declared the parameter as `char[6]`, that serves only as documentation; to the compiler it's the same as `char*`.

Another possibility is to make the local buffer static; but beware that the function will no longer be reentrant or thread-safe, which could lead to weird bugs.

> Why is using those global variables causing the output of getAlarmTime() to go so wonky?

My guess would be that, when you initialise the local variables with constants, the compiler eliminates them and uses the constants instead. This moves the array to somewhere else in the stack, where it happens not to be overwritten before you examine it. But this is all in the realms of undefined behaviour, so the exact details aren't of any practical interest.